Maps & Minification Problem (Teavm JS & Java)
JS files are from Eaglercraft's src code
(Minecraft java --> Eaglercraft HTML/JS) (How? teavm)
I have two JS files a .js and a .js.map, i want to unminify it but its easier said then done.
--- What I tried to do ---
I found Sokra's source-map-visualization a site for un-minifying, so I uploaded the JS then the map, and then it asks me to upload the Java files so I started to look at the needed file name, go through the folders to find it, select it and upload it
A little in, I realized it may require a lot of files so I checked with sources. and I was right, I would have to manually find and upload 1258 java files so I figured I might as well ask others if they know what would work in this specific situation.

Code in Google Drive
Google Drive contains: rar with the src code for Eaglercraft 1.5.2 (and MC 1.5.2 i believe), and team from the github, and a readme.md before I moved it to google drive as a precaution to any copyright claims.
virustotal if need be

If you helped or tried thanks
- kaleb1583

its two js files that are thousands of lines plus a bunch of java files, the rar is 675mb i cant really do that.

So, what is it you want help with? It's unclear what you want an answer to, since there is no obvious question or problem

"i want to unminify it". i have a js and .js.map and i want to use the map to unminify it but i dont know how to or what tool or software or website i can use to do so

its js but it was java turned into js, i said java/js since the rar has both

i found how to do it (sort of)
